# Specifying number of decimals in Text Field with Number Formatter

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

In a Cocoa application, I am using a large number of “Text Field with Number Formatter” objects.  The objects improve the presentation of data by adding commas where appropriate so the number "123456" is presented as "123,456".  That is helpful when the number is of float type, and populated using the following code:

```
[OutR2C2 setFloatValue:MyVariable2 ];
```

Well, the number "123456.567" is presented as "123,456.567," and the number "123456.5" is presented as "123,456.5.".

I need to be able to specify that there will always be two digits after the decimal, as in 123,456.50  or 123,456.56  etc. for all numbers presented.  In the properties for this object I don’t see any way to set the number of decimal points.

How can I do that while using the “Text Field with Number Formatter” object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have something like this:

`NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];`

`[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];`

Followed by this:

`[formatter setFormat:@"###.##"];`

You need to switch that to:

`[formatter setFormat:@"###.00"];`

This will make your numbers always show two decimal places.

Alternatively you can use:

`[formatter setFormat:@"##0.00"];`

If you want to show a 0 before the decimal point if it's a <1 value.  (For example .44 would be displayed as 0.44).

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate the assistance on this question. The response helped me find the solution shown below.  I am posting it as an answer to the question so it might help others with the same question

In this example, there are two NSTextField objects on a document and displayed by the Interface Builder in an .xib file.

In the .h file, in the @interface section …

```
@interface MyViewController : NSWindowController {
@private

    IBOutlet NSTextField *Out1;
    IBOutlet NSTextField *Out2;

// other code goes here

}



In the .m file, in the @implementation section…


    @implementation MyViewController

    -(void)awakeFromNib
    {

    // set decimal places 

        NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter =
        [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
        NSMutableDictionary *newAttributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        [numberFormatter setFormat:@"###,##0;(###,##0)"]; 
    //[numberFormatter1 setFormat:@"###,##0.00;(###,##0.00)"]; // for two decimal places.


        [newAttributes setObject:[NSColor redColor] forKey:@"NSColor"];
        [numberFormatter setTextAttributesForNegativeValues: newAttributes];


       [[Out1 cell] setFormatter:numberFormatter];
       [[Out2 cell] setFormatter:numberFormatter];



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I also appreciate both the answer and solution.

For those who look for a solution in Swift, here might be one of them.

```
class NumberFormatterWithFraction_2 : NumberFormatter {

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    minimumIntegerDigits = 1
    minimumFractionDigits = 2
    maximumFractionDigits = 2
    roundingMode = .halfDown
  }

}
```

Then, specify the class defined above as a Custom class of Number Formatter in the Interface Builder of recent Xcode. That would resemble `[formatter setFormat:@"##0.00"];`

For details, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter